# How to force ActionCable to disconnect all clients when deploying new code to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actioncable

I have an application that stores a count of all connections to an actioncable channel, incrementing it on `subscribed`, and decrementing it on `unsubscribed`. However I've found an issue where deploying to Heroku won't `unsubscribed` the active connections when the server (Puma) goes down. Thus when the new version of the application spins up, the connection count is higher than what it should be.

Code for my particular channel:

```
class PostChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  attr_reader :subscribers

  def subscribed
    channel_name = "TestChannel#{params[:post_id]}"
    stream_from channel_name
    user_ids = active_users channel_name
    user_ids << connection.current_user.id
    update_users channel_name, user_ids
  end

  def unsubscribed
    channel_name = "TestChannel#{params[:post_id]}"
    user_ids = active_users channel_name
    user_ids.delete_at(user_ids.index(connection.current_user.id) ||
                       user_ids.length)
    update_users channel_name, user_ids
  end

  def active_users(channel_name)
    JSON.parse(Redis.current.hget('actioncable', channel_name) || '[]')
  end

  def update_users(channel_name, user_ids)
    Redis.current.hset('actioncable', channel_name, user_ids.to_json)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
      channel_name,
      users: user_ids,
      action: 'UsersChanged'
    )
  end
end
```

How do I force ActionCable to unsubscribe all active connections on a deployment to Heroku?

Answer (score 3):

You could define a rake task disconnecting all clients, and then run it with heroku release dynos (so it runs every time you deploy):

procfile:

```
release: bundle exec rake reset_action_cable_consumers
```

rake task:

```
# reset_action_cable_consumers.rake

# This should work
ActionCable.server.remote_connections.disconnect

# Other solution
App.cable.subscriptions.each{|subscription| subscription.unsubscribe()}
```

Comment: Yeah this was the solution I was thinking of, I'll give it a shot

Comment: but it will not reconnect users unless they refresh the page?

Comment: @NicolasMaloeuvre this was not asked in the question, so no it won't.

Comment: Actually @NicolasMaloeuvre the client library I'm using (ActionCable npm package), reconnects if it misses 2 heartbeat pings from the server, so it should